# How to store and use opening hour information in flutter firebase?

Tags: list, firebase, flutter, dictionary, google-cloud-firestore

I am building an app in flutter which requires the storage of opening hours in firebase. I have decided to store the data in this format:

```
0: [9,17], //Monday
1: Null, //Tuesday
```

Etc Etc. The openingHours field is a list of map values. The key corresponds to the day, then the hours are the value, being a list of integers if open, or a null value if closed. I am struggling however to take the list from the json file from firebase and store it in a list of maps value in flutter, in a class called "business", and similarly upload the data to flutter.

The business object looks like this:

```
    class Business{
  String businessId;
  String name;
  String photoUrl;
  Map<int, List<int>> openingHours;

  CommentModel({
    this.name,
    this.businessId,
    this.photoUrl,
    this.openingHours
  });

  CommentModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    name = json['name'];
    businessId = json['businessId'];
    photoUrl = json['photoUrl'];
    openingHours = json['openingHours'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['name'] = this.name;
    data['businessId'] = this.businessId;
    data['photoUrl'] = this.photoUrl;
    data['openingHours'] = this.openingHours;
    return data;
  }
}
```

I am pretty aware I'm quite far off the mark with this one and would appreciate any help before I fully try and implement this into my currently working elsewhere design and cause some irreversible damage XD.

Answer (score 0):

0: {"open": "7:00","close: "20:00"}

1: null,

2: {"open": "7:00","close: "20:00"}

Comment: Ah thanks, and how would I do the whole toJson and fromJson for that?